# Visual Studio Nesting html,css and ts files

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2013, typescript, nested

I saw a visual studio project which consists of a folder html,css and ts files where html file is the parent file and css and ts are child files.

The thing is the project doesn't use the file nesting extension(I have already checked that) and the html,css and ts files all have different logos than the normal standard.

Html (The parent nodes) logo is a file with a blue circle and css and ts files(child nodes) logo have blue arrow files.

P.S. This is my first post in this forum so I'm not able to upload an image else I would have shared a screen shot of the project with you guys for better understanding of my problem.

Comment: Nesting is done through the VS project file. You set a dependency on another item in the project in the project file. Unload the project if you want to edit the file directly in VS. There are plenty of answers on SO on how to do this. All the extension does is make this process easier.

Comment: Adding dependency in the project file is a manual process.Is there anyway to automate this ?.

What I want to know is that is there any way where I can add a new web project which by default contains html,css and js/ts files and has them in proper parent child hierarchy ??

Comment: How would it know to associate a CSS/JS/TS file automatically with an HTML file? You need to define that relationship. I don't know of a default behavior in any type of project that does what you describe. Therefore, I'm apt to believe that some extension, or manual process, was used to create the dependencies. If you don't want to manually edit the project file, use an extension (I use NestIn and it works great).

Comment: That's what I wanted to know...if there was some automatic process for this available or not...or any way to explicitly define your own relationship (which is not available in File Nesting) *sigh*...well thanks for the help

Comment: Not that I know of, but maybe someone else knows of one. You could also attempt to write your own extension to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok just open task manager
And end process tree of 'code.exe'
And restart

Comment: How does terminating "code.exe" solve the issue?